# Is it possible to tie initial SAML request to the SAML Assertion received from the IDP?

Tags: saml, pkce

I am looking for a way to tie the SAML request I make to an IDP to the SAML Assertion it sends back. Is there a way to do that?

One idea I had was to use the SessionIndex. I have found that in practice, in some cases the SessionIndex can be used to do this, because some SAML servers return the ID from the initial request as the SessionIndex in the SAML Assertion, but I have also found that is not done universally / does not seem to be required by the spec. It seems like the intention of the SessionIndex is just to tie together the SAML Assertion with subsequent calls, e.g. logout attempts, so there's no requirement that it be tied to the initial request. I draw that conclusion from [this post](https://community.broadcom.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=755743#bmfa23bd1d-f59e-45d0-b31b-5672e06596c0%3C/subjectconfirmation%3E%3C/subject%3E%3C/authnstatement), which says "At least one assertion containing an MUST contain a element with at least one element containing a Method of urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer. If the identity provider supports the Single Logout profile, defined in Section 4.4, any such authentication statements MUST include a SessionIndex attribute to enable per-session logout requests by the service provider." I have also reviewed [this post](http://blog.sweetxml.org/2008/01/saml-v20-sessionindex-what-and-why.html), which breaks down the use of SessionIndex and I think supports the same conclusion.

I don't see anything else in the spec that seems promising, but I am hoping I may be missing something - is there any reliable way to pass data to the IDP in a SAML request and get it back in the SAML Assertion?

FYI, the reason why I want this is to support mobile sso login where my mobile device uses an embedded web browser to make an OAuth2 call to my web server, the web server authenticates the user, and then sends back an authorization code to the mobile device with a redirect. I want to use PKCE to secure the OAuth2 flow between the mobile device and the web server, but that requires me to be able to tie the initial request call to the final redirect with a shared code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two methods that can be used, so long as the user journey starts where it should, on the page they are trying to get to, making this a service-provider initiated authentication request. As the service provider in a SAML-based federation, you start the process by sending the identity provider an **AuthnRequest**.

The first method availables comes by tracking the AuthnRequest's `ID`. In a good SAML implementation, that AuthnRequest's ID is big and random and likely not repeatable in our lifetime. [The SAML Profiles spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/56782/sstc-saml-profiles-errata-2.0-wd-07.pdf#page=19) says on lines 625-626:

> If the containing message is in response to an `<AuthnRequest>`, then
> the `InResponseTo` attribute MUST match the request's `ID`.

Therefore, as long as you keep track of the ID's that you send out, then you can tie the Request's `ID` to the Response's `inResponseTo`.

The second method at your disposal is `RelayState`. This is an aptly-named element of an AuthnRequest that you can use to transfer state to the Identity Provider an back. This is a field that you can use as you see fit as the service provider, and the responder has to send it back. [The Bindings spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/56779/sstc-saml-bindings-errata-2.0-wd-06.pdf#page=8) says on lines 265-271:

> Some bindings define a "RelayState" mechanism for preserving and
> conveying state information. When such a mechanism is used in
> conveying a request message as the initial step of a SAML protocol, it
> places requirements on the selection and use of the binding
> subsequently used to convey the response. Namely, if a SAML request
> message is accompanied by RelayState data, then the SAML responder
> MUST return its SAML protocol response using a binding that also
> supports a RelayState mechanism, and it MUST place the exact
> RelayState data it received with the request into the corresponding
> RelayState parameter in the response.

As such, you can put something in that field, and the IdP must parrot it back untouched. You should make sure that what you put in there doesn't compromise the user or security, so just be mindful of how you use it. It's going to end up in logs somewhere.